# When passing in a collection of sObjects to a Queueable what values are used?

Tags: apex, queueable-interface

Suppose I pass in a collection of sObjects to a queueable.  Does the queueable execute on the values of the sobjects field that get passed when the queueable is invoked? Given it is possible for these field values to get modified by the synchronous call, is the Asynch Apex platform smart enough to account for that?

Comment: Please try to include obvious tags. When a question relates to `[apex]`, it should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

sObjects (and other objects, for that matter) that are instance variables in Queueables and in Batch Apex classes are serialized and stored, and then deserialized at the time the Asynchronous Apex is executed. Field values for sObjects are *not* refreshed unless your code performs an explicit SOQL query to do so.

Take this Queueable, for example:

```
public class TestQueueable implements Queueable {
    private Account a;

    public TestQueueable(Account a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void execute(System.QueueableContext qc) {
        System.debug('Account Name is ' + a.Name);
    }
}
```

If you run in Anonymous Apex

```
Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
insert a;

System.enqueueJob(new TestQueueable(a));

a.Name = 'ACME';
update a;
```

Which Account Name prints in the Queueable, when it executes after the Anonymous Apex transaction completes?

It's important to note that the Queueable (or future, or batch) doesn't start executing until this transaction, the Anonymous Apex we're running, commits successfully and without a rollback. Chronologically, the `update` DML fires before the Queueable even begins executing.

Here's what we get back:

> 15:42:44:004 USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|Account Name is Test

One consequence of this feature is that Queueables and Batch Apex cannot have non-serializable member variables. `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`, for example, is not serializable. If we'd written

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage a = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
System.enqueueJob(new TestQueueable(a));
```

we would get back

> System.SerializationException: Not Serializable: Messaging.SingleEmailMessage

Comment: When was the `update` processed, after the `TestQueueable#execute()` or prior to it? Trying to understand what would have been the results, if the `execute()` did not fire immediately.

Comment: Prior. The Queueable is not executed until some time after its source transaction commits.(The enqueue operation would have been rolled back if an unhandled exception was thrown).

Comment: Great to know this. I had always thought that any batch (or scheduled) process always works on the latest record set, even if not explicitly retrieved.

Comment: @JayantDas Batch is a little different. This would apply to any sObjects held as batch instance variables, but not to `execute()`'s `scope` parameter, which is queried by the system.

Comment: @DavidReed not always. In edge cases Future /queuable runs even if main transaction has exception and didnt commit anything in the database

Comment: @PranayJaiswal The only case that *should* happen are platform events. If you have a live example of another case where that happens, log a bug.

Comment: They'll run if the exception is *handled*, but if the transaction is rolled back so should be all async code enqueued therein. Platform events are explicitly non-transactional.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox,  I have seen this happen few release back, I can find one reference here. https://smgoodyear.com/2015/12/04/asynchronous-apex-and-transaction-boundaries/

Need to check if still the case.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Cool stuff. So, broken in Apex but works normally in the API. That's just crazy. I'll have to test it and report it if it still exists.

Comment: Is there a replication of that behavior that doesn't involve the Data Import Wizard, but some other API client?

Comment: @sfdcfox Isn't the Simon Goodyear use case (at bottom of his blog post) expected? - Data Loader uses `AllOrNone = false` and hence SFDC will auto-retry the successes in the transaction (batch 0) and hence their futures will fire while the records in the second batch (1) will not be retried.

Comment: @cropredy Regarding the last bit, Simon was using the Data Import Wizard, so the logs appear to be concatenated. It depends if the records were created successfully or not. If no accounts survived, then the future method is wrong, but if the first 200 survived, then it is correct. I'll test it out.

Comment: @sfdcfox - hmm I never use data import wizard but would still imagine allornone = false as that is the most practical way to import data.

Comment: @DavidReed under what scenarios would I not have to re-query? is it correct to say you almost always want to requery?

Comment: @user11235813 If you want to ensure you have current data, you should re-query. The only time you would not do so is if you are taking action based on the specific field values passed to your class, rather than the current state of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add what David said.

Future / Queueable are just tools that allow us to do another job asynchronously after the main transaction has ended. It's intentionally made dumb so that developers can make it do what they want. There is no SLA for future/queuable calls. They can happen the next second or can happen after 30 mins or even an hour.

Now there can be various use cases like you have to sync data to very transaction oriented external system and you use Queuable. Now even if you delete that record(before queuable has executed), you still want the entity to be sent for audit purpose. Here Queueable gives you that power

If you want the latest data, you can always query it. It suits the need of both Data at the time of main DML happened as well as the time when the actual call is made.